# Fetch from API and read length of object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch json from an API and read the total number of entries in the data. My current code looks like this:

```
fetch("https://api.site.com/v1/lessons", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
                (response) =>
                    (this.lessons = response.map((e) => ({
                        id: e.id,
                    }))))
  .then(console.log(this.lessons.length))
```

However, this returns '0' in the console when I know that it should return '20' as there are 20 entries in the retrieved json.

Here is an example of the data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13652,
    "customer_type": "family",
    "salutation": "",
    "first_name": "Frank & Tina",
  },
  {
    "id": 13653,
    "customer_type": "individual",
    "salutation": "",
    "first_name": "Jordan",
  }
]
```

I'm very new to this, so I'm not great at trouble shooting. I handled a similar situation elsewhere with the same method and it works fine. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It's a typo, last then statement does not have a function callback
`.then(console.log(this.lessons.length))` should be `.then(() => console.log(this.lessons.length))`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you Krzysztof.